# Liquid: resolve a link function from a variable

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Well, I got a `menu.yaml` like so:

```
  entries:
  - title: Welcome to my site
    url: /

  - title: Über mich
    link: about_DE.md

  - title: About me
    link: about_EN.md

  - title: Parcour
    url: /parcours/
```

As you can see, I sometimes use an explicit url, sometimes the page name, that can directly be resolved with `{% link _pages/about_DE.md %}`

Now my problem: How to do that in a loop, when I can't write the link explictly but rather must use a variable like `item.link`?

```
{% for item in site.data.header.entries %}

    {% if item.link %}
    {% link item.link %}
    {% else %}
    {{ item.url }}
    {% endif %}
```

> Liquid Exception: Could not find document '{{item.link}}' in tag 'link'.

How can I tell Liquid, that item.link is a link, note already the page name. And then resolve it to an actual URL? Or is there a corresponding filter?

Comment: I would simply write the links as URLs, so they are all the same.

Comment: Hi @JoostS, my trouble is, that `about_EN.md` might stand for `seo/expert-javascript/my-hometown/ramble-tag/book-me` ;-)   (by way of permalink: liquid-header...)

Answer (score 1):

While traversing the *for* loop, if the item has a `link` then we look through all our pages which one has that path, that will be our page.

```
{% for item in site.data.menu.entries %}
{% if item.link %}
 {% assign apost = site.pages | where:"path",item.link  | first %}
   <a href="{{apost.url}}">{{apost.title}}</a>
{% endif %}
{%endfor %}
```